# How can I solve for the Jacobian matrix of a complementary log function?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, partial-derivative, jacobian

Suppose that $h(\mathbf{s})=1-[\exp(e^{\beta_0+\beta_1(||\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x}||)^2})]^{-1}$, where both **s** and **x** are $1\times2$ vectors. How can I find the Jacobian matrix's determinant $|J(h(\mathbf{s}))|$?

**My work:**

For some reason, I'm not able to determine the form of the Jacobian matrix here. I'm seeing that:

$$J(h(\mathbf{s}))=\left( \begin{matrix} \dfrac{\partial h(\mathbf{s})}{\partial s_1} & \dfrac{\partial h(\mathbf{s})}{\partial s_2} \end{matrix} \right),$$ which does not follow the typical square form of a Jacobian matrix. Is this because $h(\mathbf s)$ returns a scalar value (which I am assuming this function returns a scalar value), going from a two-dimensional space to one-dimensional space?

**Update:**

Here, we have a 2-1 dimension reduction. I have heard that we could augment the output space with an extra variable, then use an identity transformation. However, I am not aware of how to implement this suggestion.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, then its Jacobian will be a $\mathscr{M}_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ matrix. Square Jacobian matrices occur if the function maps a Euclidean space to itself.

Comment: @Anthony Okay, so our input $\mathbf{s}$ is 1x2. Am I correct in thinking that $h(\mathbf{s})$ will return a single value? If it does, then our output is 1x1. So then my form of $J(h(\mathbf{s}))$ would be correct.

Comment: I'm not sure your function is well-defined though. Are you sure you haven't made a mistake whilst copying it ? What do you expect the exponential of the square of a vector to be ?

Comment: @Anthony After a quick example in R, the exponential of the square of a 1x2 vector will still be 1x2. I suppose that $h(\mathbf{s})$ will be a 1x2 vector, as well. I meant to have (s-x) be the distance between two ordered pairs, so I will update my post to reflect this. (Edit: The post has been updated.)

Comment: Looking at your edit, you indeed have $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, meaning the Jacobian is $1\times2$.

Comment: @Anthony I added an update describing an approach that may work, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's use a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Next, define the following cascade of variables
$$\eqalign{
y &= (s-x)\quad&\implies\quad dy = ds,\;\;dx=0\;\;\{x=constant\} \\
\alpha &=\beta_0+\beta_1(y:y)\quad&\implies\quad d\alpha=2\beta_1(y:dy) \\
\gamma &= e^\alpha\quad&\implies\quad d\gamma=\gamma\,d\alpha \\
h &= 1-e^{-\gamma}\quad&\implies\quad dh=e^{-\gamma}d\gamma \\
}$$
Now successively substitute into that last differential
$$\eqalign{
dh &= (1-h)\,d\gamma \\
  &= \gamma(1-h)\,d\alpha \\
  &= 2\gamma\beta_1(1-h)\;y:dy \\
  &= 2\gamma\beta_1(1-h)\;(s-x):ds \\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial s}
  &= 2\gamma\beta_1(1-h)\;(s-x) \\
}$$
**NB:**   This is the *gradient* of $h$ with respect to $s$, not the *Jacobian*.

Since the function is symmetric in the variables $\{s,x\}$,
we get the following gradient (for free)
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}
  &= 2\gamma\beta_1(1-h)\;(x-s) \\
}$$

Comment: This looks great! How did you get d$\alpha$, specifically with the trace involving ds? I've never seen that before. Also, now that we have the Jacobian, how can I use the transformation of variables technique? That involves finding the determinant, but we can't take the determinant of this Jacobian since it's not square.

Comment: Construct the diagonal matrices $S={\rm Diag}(s),\,X={\rm Diag}(x)$, then the gradient becomes a diagonal matrix as well, i.e. $$G=2\gamma\beta_1(1-h)(S-X)$$ Now you can calculate its determinant.  But _why_ do you require a determinant in the first place? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Okay, this is making a bit more sense to me. However, I'm still confused how you obtained d$\alpha$. What did you differentiate w.r.t. to obtain $(s-x):ds$?This solution holds up for vectors s and x (which are 1x2), right? I've never seen Diag() apply to a vector before.

Comment: I'm also surprised to see that $h$ appears in $\frac{\partial h}{\partial s}$ when it wasn't in the function $h(s)$ to begin with.

Comment: I've re-worked the answer to show how $d\alpha$ is obtained. The reason $h$ appears is because we're dealing with exponential functions, i.e. $\frac{de^u}{dx}=e^u\,\frac{du}{dx}.\;$ Why does $e^u$ appear on the RHS?

Comment: Oh okay. This makes much more sense. Thank you, greg!